# I opened many csv files as one and now I need to add names of this files into

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, glob

I have a lot of csv files in folder and the have names like XCV123.csv XCF456.csv, DFT456.csv and etc. I opened them and saved as one but the I saw that there is no names of this files in csv. DF looks like below (of course one csv has a lot of rows):

```
A B C 
1 2 3 
5 2 3
6 5 2
```

So what I am looking for is DF or CSV like this

```
A B C Name
1 2 3 XCV123
5 2 3 XCF456
6 5 2 DFT456
```

I opened this with code:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

with open('/opt/home/main.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == 'main.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                singleFile.write(line)
```

But I have to add something to this code and I have no idea what... Thanks for all your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume here that:

- all your csv files have the same header
- all your csv files have the same delimiter: comma
- you can use quoted fields in your csv files
- you can erase the file at each run

Then, you could change your code to:

```
# use mode wb to control end of lines and overwrite the output file
with open('/opt/home/main.csv', 'wb') as singleFile:
    do_header = True                 # add 1! header
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == 'main.csv':
            pass
        else:
            with open(csv, 'rb') as file:
                line = next(file)
                if do_header:         # only on first pass
                    singlefile.write(line.rstrip() + b',Name\r\n')
                    do_header = False
                for line in file:
                    singlefile.write(line.rstrip() + ',"{}"\r\n'.format(csv).encode())
            singleFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for idea but I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in line 14 "do_header == False"

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz: My bad I had forgotten 2 closing parens. Fixed.

Comment: There was also a small mistake with "singleFile". In next lines there is "singlefile". But it is nothing. The bigger issue is that it stopsIteration after one file, below code:
<ipython-input-24-6869b3d89a68> in <module>
      7         else:
      8             with open(csv, 'rb') as file:
----> 9                 line = next(file)
     10                 if do_header:         # only on first pass
     11                     singleFile.write(line.rstrip() + b',Name\r\n')

Answer (score 1):

using `pandas` and `pathlib`

you can use `.stem` on a pathlib object to return the filename without the extension.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

files = Path('/to/csv/files').glob('*.csv') #rglob if you have sub directories.

dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file).assign(Name=file.stem) for file in files])

dfs.to_csv('singleFile.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I get error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'"

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz my fault, forgot to add the module import - try again

Comment: I fixed it but I get another error: ValueError: No objects to concatenate...

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz did you pass in the path to your csv folder?

Comment: I did and I saw that there is a lack of letter "s" in line with dfs=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) but it didn't  help